# How to make a systemd timer that runs every 2 days?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-timer

I am looking a guide to understand how OnCalendar works. I don't understand ..... Please how can I make a systemd timer runs every 2 days?

```
[Unit]
Description=systemd every 2 days.

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00:00:00
Persistent=true
Unit=personal.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: I suspect `OnCalendar=2day` will work

Comment: @Stewart It doesn't work!

Comment: When you say, "every two days",  is ther any way to get it to repeat?  i.e.  mon, wed, fri, sun, then monday again?

Comment: Every 48h. N ot specific days!!!

Comment: @GAD3R your example works every 14 days...I want every 48h or 2 days

Comment: @user14770539 "Every 48h" is ambiguous see my answer for why.

Answer (score 4):

See [systemd.time(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html).

This tells us a daily statment is:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00:00:00
```

The third `*` represents which day of the month.  So:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-01 00:00:00
```

Means on the first of every month.  The term "Every two days" would require a starting point, otherwise it's ambiguous.  It could be every two days since system boot, or every even day since Jan 1 2020, or every odd day since the epoch, etc. Is today an even or odd day?  It's much easier to define the specific days you want to schedule things.

This would work:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31 00:00:00
```

This says it will run on every odd day of the month which is pretty close to your bi-daily requirement.

---

If it's just since boot, then this should work:

```
OnBootSec=2d
```

However if you reboot, then the schedule resets and you won't trigger for another two days.

---

You can see details of `OnBootSec=`, `OnCalendarSec=` and other options in [systemd.timer(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#)

---

You can test other forms using `systemd-analyze calendar <expr>`.  This will give you some info about your expression without the need to edit the timer and try to enable it.

Example:

```
$ systemd-analyze calendar *-*-1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31 00:00:00
  Original form: *-*-1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31              
Normalized form: *-*-01,03,05,07,09,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31 00:00:00
    Next elapse: Sun 2021-01-17 00:00:00 CET                                 
       (in UTC): Sat 2021-01-16 23:00:00 UTC                                 
       From now: 1 day 1h left                                               

  Original form: 00:00:00                   
Normalized form: *-*-* 00:00:00             
    Next elapse: Sat 2021-01-16 00:00:00 CET
       (in UTC): Fri 2021-01-15 23:00:00 UTC
       From now: 1h 55min left
```

Comment: It doesn't work both of your examples!

Comment: I'll take a look

Comment: Thank you very much Stewart! I want if I use today my pc and my service runs ...I want my service run again every 48h. EXAMPLE ...Today friday just run service. I open my pc monday, not run service. I run my pc tuesday and I want to run the service again. Did you understand?

Comment: I added those details to the answer using `Persistent=` and `OnActiveSec=`.  Note that in your example, if you ran the timer on Friday, and you left your computer off on Sunday, then the deadline is missed, and the timer will run as soon as you boot up again.  It doesn't skip deadlines and wait for the next one on Tuesday.

Comment: Ok I use `OnActiveSec=2d, Persistent=true` then I see how it works. Thank you again. I let you know next days..

Comment: I re-read the section about `Presistent=` on the man page.  It only works with `OnCalendar=`,  Meaning if you missed a calendar deadline, the timer will run immediately after boot.  It doesn't work on `OnActiveSec=`.  I'm removing that part of the answer since it's wrong.  The choices you are left with are the `OnBootSec=2d` (time since boot), or define the calendar days you want it to boot like I did (every odd day of the month).

Comment: It doesn't work with `OnBootSec=2d or OnUnitActiveSec=2d` because every boot the machine goes service later. Example: If I boot at 11.00AM timer goes monday at 11.00AM. If I boot again at 11.15 the timer goes moday 11.15AM. So It will never run.

Comment: Then you REALLY need to decide on a calendar schedule.

Comment: Do you have any guide to learn more about OnCalendar option? `man systemd-.timer` not help me. I want some guide with specific examples.

Comment: [`man systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) helps, but [`man systemd.time`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events) has a great section that is even better when it describes how to make expressions for `OnCalendar=`.